# Alter React parent component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, mern

I am trying to create a simple SPA (without Router). It has also a simple structure: a component per section:

- Home
- Services
- Products

  - Product
  - Modal
- Contact us

As you can see the component **Products** has two sub-components **Product** and **Modal**. These are iterated so many times as JSON objects there are:

**Products.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";
import "./Products.css";
import { products } from "./products.json";

import Product from "./Product/Product";
import Modal from "./Modal/Modal";

class Products extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section id='products'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='row'>
            {products.map(product => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <Product
                    image={"/img/" + product.image}
                    name={product.name}
                    target={product.target}
                  />
                  <Modal
                    id={product.target}
                    title={product.name}
                    body={ReactHtmlParser(product.body)}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Products;
```

Each product has a *More Info* button what opens the modal and this has another button *Budget* (**"Presupuestar"**):

[image: Modal]

That function should "change the state" of **Contact us** component (a simple contact us form):

[image: Form]

The component has the following code:

**Contact.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Contact.css";

class Contact extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = { budget: "Contact" };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <section id='contact'>
                <div className='container'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>
                            <div className='contact-form'>
                                <form>
                                    ...
                                    {/* Subject */}
                                    <div className='form-group'>
                                        <div className='input-group'>
                                          <span className='input-group-addon' />
                                          <input
                                            type='text'
                                            className='form-control'
                                            id='subject'
                                            aria-describedby='Subject'
                                            placeholder='Subject'
                                            readonly='readonly'
                                            value={this.state.budget}
                                          />
                                        </div>
                                        {/* /form-group */}
                                    </div>
                                    {/* /Subject */}
                                    ...
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

I guess then I should create a function in the **Modal** component to trigger with an `onClick="setSubject"` in the *Budget* (**"Presupuestar"**) button. What I don't know is how to alter the other component's state.

A quick summary: I have to make the following state update:

[image: How to]

I was reading [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940053/alter-state-of-parent-from-a-child-component-react-js) but I didn't get how to apply in my scenario. Any ideas?

Comment: you actually want to changestate of contact component when the modal or product is clicked?

Comment: I guess so, I want to change the **Contact** component's state when clicking on the **Modal**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should either but the `clickHandler` function of the button in the `App` component that wrap the whole components and then pass it to the `Products` component then to `Modal` component but it's not a good practice,
Or you can use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) a state management system that let you control your state through the whole app.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need a function to `change the state` of another component. The smart way to do that is using an **intermediary thing** to connect 2 component together. There is two way to solve this problem.

1. The easiest way is you can transfer subject via URL (URL is "**the intermediary thing**"). When you click the button **Presupuestar** you can change URL to page contact like this:

`/contact?subject=whatever you want`

Then, at **Contact** component, you just need to parse URL to get subject (you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript) to know how to parse from URL). You can see [my example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8n5ro79wp8).

2. The second way is creating a service use **singleton pattern** to transfer subject from **Modal** to **Contact** form. You can see [my example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zq734vmwn3).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like this

Create a main app component which will contain all these these three comps

Add a function in app component "changeContacts"

Send it to both the product as well as contacts

Here is an explanation

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Contact ref="contacts"/>
        <Products changeContacts={this.changeContacts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  changeContacts = (newState) => {
    this.refs.contacts.changeState(newState)
  };
}

class Contact extends Component {
    state = { text:"Old Text" }
    render() { 
        return ( <div style={{fontSize:50,backgroundColor:'red'}}>{this.state.text}</div> );
    }
    changeState = (newState) =>{
        this.setState(newState);
    }
}
class Modal extends Component {
  render() { 
    return ( <div onClick={() => this.props.onClick({text:"New State Text"})}>This is a modal</div> );
  }
}
class Products extends Component {
    state = {  }
    render() { 
        return ( <div>
            <h1>Products List</h1>
            <Modal onClick={this.props.changeContacts} />
            <Modal onClick={this.props.changeContacts}/>
            <Modal onClick={this.props.changeContacts}/>
        </div> );
    }
}
```